# Adding a Bar Graph/Library for Graphs in a PHP Program

Tags: php, mysql, graph

I am planning to place a bar graph for my PHP program but I am not sure how to do it. I've seen some examples but I got lost on the "download this download that" portion of the explanation. I'm not sure how to import or how to install the necessary files for graphs. I have this "Sorting" feature for my program and instead of displaying the data in a tabular manner, I am planning to change it to a "Bar Graph" model.

Can you suggest easy methods to achieve this? I could start with manually inputting the values for the graph but I think it would be better if it roots from the database or a certain SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Morris chart

http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/258/embed?html,js,output

its good and free and you can get file and documentation from

http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Topnew SVG Charts, one single PHP file (9kb), to create Bar Chart, Pie Charts, Line Charts, Vertical stack bar charts, multiple bar charts, overlapping bar charts, etc.: http://topnew.net/chart/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you need in graphical mode or in text, but i developed a bar graph library for PHP-CLI.You will find the advertisement of the library launch at [my blog](https://rafamartin10.blogspot.com/2021/09/visualizacion-de-datos-en-graficos-de.html) and the code can be found on Github: https://github.com/vivesweb/cli-graph-ml. Hope this can help you [Example of bar graph in PHP-CI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROfa7.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29934011)